# Keeping only the x largest groups with data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I have recently started using the data.table package in R, but I recently stumbled into an issue that I do not know how to tackle with data.table.

Sample data:

```
set.seed(1)
library(data.table)
dt = data.table(group=c("A","A","A","B","B","B","C","C"),value = runif(8))
```

I can add a group count with the statement

```
dt[,groupcount := .N ,group]
```

but now I only want to keep the x groups with the largest value for `groupcount`. Let's assume `x=1` **for the example.**

I tried chaining as follows:

```
dt[,groupcount := .N ,group][groupcount %in% head(sort(unique(groupcount),decreasing=TRUE),1)]
```

But since group A and B both have three elements, they both remain in the data.table. I only want the x largest groups where x=1, so I only want one of the groups (A or B) to remain. I assume this can be done in a single line with data.table. Is this true, and if yes, how?

---

To clarify: **x is an arbitrarily chosen number here.** The function should also work with x=3, where it would return the 3 largest groups.

Comment: Oops, not sure how that slipped in there. Corrected.

Comment: Another option: `dt[dt[order(-groupcount), unique(group)[seq_len(x)]], on = "group"]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about making use of the order of the `groupcount`

```
setorder(dt, -groupcount)

x <- 1   
dt[group %in% dt[ , unique(group)][1:x] ]

#   group     value groupcount
# 1:     A 0.2655087          3
# 2:     A 0.3721239          3
# 3:     A 0.5728534          3


x <- 3
dt[group %in% dt[ , unique(group)][1:x] ]


#     group     value groupcount
# 1:     A 0.2655087          3
# 2:     A 0.3721239          3
# 3:     A 0.5728534          3
# 4:     B 0.9082078          3
# 5:     B 0.2016819          3
# 6:     B 0.8983897          3
# 7:     C 0.9446753          2
# 8:     C 0.6607978          2

## alternative syntax
# dt[group %in% unique(dt$group)[1:x] ]
```

Comment: Thanks! Does exactly what I was looking for. So in a single line that becomes: `dt[,groupcount := .N ,group][group %in% dt[order(-groupcount) , unique(group)][1:x]]`

Comment: @Florian - You can even put the order in the chain too `dt[,groupcount := .N, group][order(-groupcount)][ groupcount == (max(groupcount)), ][ group %in% unique(group)[1:x] ]`

Answer (score 3):

Here is a method that uses a join.

```
x <- 1

dt[dt[, .N, by=group][order(-N)[1:x]], on="group"]
   group     value N
1:     A 0.2655087 3
2:     A 0.3721239 3
3:     A 0.5728534 3
```

The inner data.frame is aggregated to count the observations and the position of the x largest groups is retrieved using `order` subset using the value of x. The resulting data frame is then joined onto the original by group.

Comment: This is much cleaner way

Comment: Thanks lmo! This is a very nice solution.

Comment: Or `dt[dt[, .N, by=group][order(-N), head(group, x)], on=.(group)]`.

Answer (score 2):

We can do

```
x <- 1
dt[dt[, {tbl <- table(group)
         nm <- names(tbl)[tbl==max(tbl)]
        if(length(nm) < x) rep(TRUE, .N)
        else group %in% sample(names(tbl)[tbl==max(tbl)], x)}]]
```

Comment: Hi akrun, sorry if I phrased my question incorrectly. This works perfectly for x=1, but not with x=3, in which case I would expect all groups to remain. Is this also doable with data.table?